# How to list all deployed aws resources with aws cdk

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-cdk

I have an AWS Cdk deployer application that deployed multiple resources in AWS. The application uses a config file that acts as an input file and using that it deployed multiple was ecs task in a fargate cluster and placed them behind an application load balancer.

Is there any way to get all the components/AWS services that are being deployed when I run `cdk deploy --all`. I'm trying to understand without using a separate boto3 function if there is any way which was cdk provides.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After synth, from the `cdk.out` [CloudAssembly](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/@aws-cdk_cx-api.CloudAssembly.html):

```py
import aws_cdk.cx_api as cx_api

cloud_assembly = cx_api.CloudAssembly("cdk.out")
resources = [stack.template["Resources"] for stack in cloud_assembly.stacks]
```

After deploy, with the [DescribeStackResources](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeStackResources.html) or [ListStackResources](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/APIReference/API_ListStackResources.html) APIs:

```sh
aws cloudformation describe-stack-resources --stack-name MyStack
```

Both return lists of CloudFormation Resource information, but with different content.  The `CloudAssembly` resources are from the local template generated by `cdk synth`.  The Resources returned from boto3 or the CLI are the deployed cloud resources with resolved names.

Comment: using the above code I am getting error: `'CloudAssembly' object is not subscribable` In my deployer application I have 3 stacks.Each one I did `cdk synth stackname` and then ran the above `CloudAssembly ` code

Comment: @Dcook My bad. I fixed the code and tested that it now works.  If you first synth with `cdk synth --all`, the script will output a list with 3 maps - one map of resources for each of your app's stacks.